# Trouble getting an SVG to other side of card body and need to reverse it

Tags: css, svg, frontend

I have an SVG that I need to be on the opposite side of the card and reversed. Any changes I seem to make only move it up a little or make it disappear. Any help would be much appreciated:
This Picture below is what I have, but the svg needs to be on the other side and turned about as to finish the paragraph.

```
<div class="row featurette" id="ourMission">
  <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
       <span class="svg-icon text-primary mb-3">
              <svg width="300" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  
              <path  d="M13.5001 5.84998C9.0001 7.64998 5.4001 12.15 5.4001 16.2C5.4001 17.1 5.4001 18 5.8501 18.45C6.7501 17.55 8.1001 17.1 9.9001 17.1C13.5001 17.1 16.6501 19.8 16.6501 23.85C16.6501 27.9 13.5001 30.6 9.9001 30.6C6.3001 31.05 4.5001 29.7 3.1501 27.45C1.8001 25.2 1.3501 22.05 1.3501 20.25C1.3501 13.05 4.9501 7.19998 12.6001 3.59998L13.5001 5.84998ZM31.9501 5.84998C27.4501 7.64998 23.8501 12.15 23.8501 16.2C23.8501 17.1 23.8501 18 24.3001 18.45C25.2001 17.55 26.5501 17.1 28.3501 17.1C31.9501 17.1 35.1001 19.8 35.1001 23.85C35.1001 27.9 31.9501 30.6 28.3501 30.6C25.2001 30.6 23.4001 29.25 22.0501 27C19.8001 25.2 19.8001 22.05 19.8001 20.25C19.8001 13.05 23.4001 7.19998 31.0501 3.59998L31.9501 5.84998Z" fill="#377dff"/>
              </svg>

            </span>


            <!-- Blockquote -->
            <figure>
              <blockquote class="blockquote blockquote-sm">
                  <!--IN The size-->
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want SVG? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/q/quotes/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman it's for a certian look. This SVG fits exactly what we need. I guess I could use the quotes and stylize them, but this seems easier to just flip it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put the svg another time after the content and apply a rotate ?

```
<div class="row featurette" id="ourMission">
  <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
       <span class="svg-icon text-primary mb-3">
              <svg width="300" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  
              <path  d="M13.5001 5.84998C9.0001 7.64998 5.4001 12.15 5.4001 16.2C5.4001 17.1 5.4001 18 5.8501 18.45C6.7501 17.55 8.1001 17.1 9.9001 17.1C13.5001 17.1 16.6501 19.8 16.6501 23.85C16.6501 27.9 13.5001 30.6 9.9001 30.6C6.3001 31.05 4.5001 29.7 3.1501 27.45C1.8001 25.2 1.3501 22.05 1.3501 20.25C1.3501 13.05 4.9501 7.19998 12.6001 3.59998L13.5001 5.84998ZM31.9501 5.84998C27.4501 7.64998 23.8501 12.15 23.8501 16.2C23.8501 17.1 23.8501 18 24.3001 18.45C25.2001 17.55 26.5501 17.1 28.3501 17.1C31.9501 17.1 35.1001 19.8 35.1001 23.85C35.1001 27.9 31.9501 30.6 28.3501 30.6C25.2001 30.6 23.4001 29.25 22.0501 27C19.8001 25.2 19.8001 22.05 19.8001 20.25C19.8001 13.05 23.4001 7.19998 31.0501 3.59998L31.9501 5.84998Z" fill="#377dff"/>
              </svg>

            </span>


            <!-- Blockquote -->
            <figure>
              <blockquote class="blockquote blockquote-sm">
                  <!--IN The size-->
                
                              <svg width="300" height="36" viewBox="0 0 36 36" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="transform:rotate(180deg)">
                  
              <path  d="M13.5001 5.84998C9.0001 7.64998 5.4001 12.15 5.4001 16.2C5.4001 17.1 5.4001 18 5.8501 18.45C6.7501 17.55 8.1001 17.1 9.9001 17.1C13.5001 17.1 16.6501 19.8 16.6501 23.85C16.6501 27.9 13.5001 30.6 9.9001 30.6C6.3001 31.05 4.5001 29.7 3.1501 27.45C1.8001 25.2 1.3501 22.05 1.3501 20.25C1.3501 13.05 4.9501 7.19998 12.6001 3.59998L13.5001 5.84998ZM31.9501 5.84998C27.4501 7.64998 23.8501 12.15 23.8501 16.2C23.8501 17.1 23.8501 18 24.3001 18.45C25.2001 17.55 26.5501 17.1 28.3501 17.1C31.9501 17.1 35.1001 19.8 35.1001 23.85C35.1001 27.9 31.9501 30.6 28.3501 30.6C25.2001 30.6 23.4001 29.25 22.0501 27C19.8001 25.2 19.8001 22.05 19.8001 20.25C19.8001 13.05 23.4001 7.19998 31.0501 3.59998L31.9501 5.84998Z" fill="#377dff"/>
              </svg>
```

Comment: thank you that was it! I